# Magento, ebizmarts SagePay token issue

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, opayo

I have a Magento store, using ebizmarts SagePay module with "Tokenized Payments" enabled.

This all works fine, until you try to checkout using a stored card/token. When clicking "Place Order" using onepagecheckout it says "Submitting order information" but then nothing happens afterwards.

I'm running SagePay in Test mode.

[edit]
Inspecting the ajax request, there is no content returned, only headers:

```
Request URL:http://test.domain.com/sgps/payment/onepageSaveOrder/?SID=84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:97
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414; __atuvc=2%7C39%2C0%7C40%2C0%7C41%2C0%7C42%2C25%7C43; frontend=84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414; adminhtml=e9035349d4a4869caf122a6f4cfca251; pettabs=1
Host:test.domain.com
Origin:http://test.domain.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://test.domain.com/checkout/onepage/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
X-Prototype-Version:1.7
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
SID:84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
payment[method]:sagepayserver
payment[sagepay_token_cc_id]:1
payment[remembertoken]:1
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 24 Oct 2013 10:22:45 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Set-Cookie:frontend=84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414; expires=Thu, 24-Oct-2013 11:22:47 GMT; path=/; domain=test.domain.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:frontend=84aa1c8883aca9c11e07f3f0734ec414; expires=Thu, 24-Oct-2013 11:22:47 GMT; path=/; domain=test.domain.com; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the module from version 3.0.6 to 3.0.9 has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Server?

Can you contact our Support team on 0845 111 4455 to check whether Token is enabled on your Test account.

If you're able to confirm a TxID for the order or TxCode along with your vendor name we may be able to check the reasons the transaction is not successful.

Our Partner, Ebizmarts, can help you too via info@ebizmarts.com.

Sage Pay Support